# vue-apollo - Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Ref<Readonly<any>>>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-apollo

**THE SITUATION:**

I am trying to integrate vue-apollo v4 with Typescript.

I am fetching a simple query using [useQuery](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/api/use-query.html#usequery) and [useResult](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/api/use-result.html#useresult).

useResult by default return this type: `Readonly<Ref<Readonly<any>>>`

**THE CODE:**

```js
import { GET_COUNTRY } from '../graphql/queries'
import { Country } from '../types'

setup() {
  const route = useRoute()
  const code = route.params.code

  const { result, loading } = useQuery(GET_COUNTRY, {code: code}, { 
    clientId: 'default', 
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-first'
  });
  const country = useResult(result, {}, (data) => data.country);

  console.log(country.name) // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Ref<Readonly<any>>>'.ts(2339)

  return {
    country,
    loading
  }
}
```

**ATTEMPT 1:**

```js
const country: Country = useResult(result, {}, (data) => data.country);
// Type 'Readonly<Ref<Readonly<any>>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Country': native, phone, capital, currency, and 6 more.ts(2740)
```

**ATTEMPT 2:**

```js
const country = useResult(result, {}, (data) => data.country as Country);
console.log(country.name) // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Ref<Readonly<any>>>'.ts(2339)
```

**ATTEMPT 3:**

```js
const country: Country = useResult(result, {}, (data) => data.country as Country);
// Type 'Readonly<Ref<Readonly<Country | {}>>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Country': native, phone, capital, currency, and 6 more.ts(2740)
```

**ATTEMPT 4:** 
After feedback from @tony19

```js
const { result, loading } = useQuery<Country>(GET_COUNTRY, {code: code});
const country = useResult(result, {}, (data) => data.country);
// Property 'country' does not exist on type '{ native: string; phone: string; capital: string; currency: string...
```

**ATTEMPT 5:** 
After edited answer from @tony19

```
// QUERY - simplified
export const GET_COUNTRY = gql`
  query getCountry($code: ID!) {
    country(code: $code) {
      code
      name
    }
  }
`
```

```
// TYPES - simplified
export interface Country {
  code: string,
  name: string
}

export type CountryQuery = {
  country: Country
}
```

```js
const { result, loading } = useQuery<CountryQuery>(GET_COUNTRY, {code: code});
const country = useResult(result, {}, (data) => data.country);
```

I am getting the following warning in vsCode:

```
 Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.
```

[image: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>']

**ATTEMPT 5b:** 
If, as in @tony19 answer, I do the following type:

```
type CountryQuery = {
  getCountry: Country
}
```

Then I am getting this error:

```
Property 'country' does not exist on type '{ getCountry: { code: string; name: string; }; }'
```

[image: Property 'country' does not exist on type '{ getCountry: { code: string; name: string; }; }']

**THE QUESTION:**

Is it possible to combine `useResult` with my own Typescript `interface`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following types:

```js
type Country = {
  name: string
}

const GET_COUNTRY = gql`
  query GetCountry {
    getCountry {
      name
    }
  }
`
```

The result should be typed to match the `GET_COUNTRY` query above:

```js
type CountryQuery = {
  getCountry: Country
}
```

Then, specify that query type as a type argument to `useQuery()`:

```js
const { result, loading } = useQuery<CountryQuery>(GET_COUNTRY, ⋯)
```

Now, the `data` argument of `useResult()`'s callback is of type `CountryQuery`, so use `data.getCountry.name` to get the country name:

```js
                                         type is CountryQuery
const country = useResult(result, {}, (data) => data.getCountry.name);
```

`result` and `country` are [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref)s, so to access the underlying data, unwrap them with `.value`:

```js
console.log(country.value);
```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-apollo-ts-demo)

Comment: Hey @tony19, thanks again. I edited the question. I think I am pretty close to solve. I am not sure if the issue I get in the **attempt 5** is a real issue, or just some quircky IDE/Vue behavior